# posix 'pthread_mutex_timedlock' infinite time as parameter

Tags: pthreads, posix

I am using

```
int pthread_mutex_timedlock(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
       const struct timespec *restrict abs_timeout);
```

What can I put in `abs_timeout` so the method will wait infinite time till lock is available?
I don't want to use `pthread_mutex_lock`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not think such a value exists in POSIX.  I expect that if you specify an invalid time value the implementation cannot handle, you might get an error such as `EINVAL`.  This means that specifying a ridiculously large time as the timeout will not work, either.